# form_with does not redirect when it ought to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm struggling with what I think is a very simple error, and yet I don't have the Rails sophistication to detect where that error is.

I have the following form:

```
<%= form_with(url: '/bills/viewer', method: :get) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :congress, 'Congress (i.e. 112)' %>
  <%= f.number_field :congress, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :bill_type, 'Bill type' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :bill_type, 'hr' %><%= ' House of Representatives' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :bill_type, 's' %><%= ' Senate' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :bill_type, 'hjres' %> <%= 'House Joint Resolution' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :bill_type, 'sjres' %><%= ' Senate Joint Resolution' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :bill_type, 'hconres' %><%= ' House Concurrent Resolution' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :bill_type, 'sconres' %><%= ' Senate Concurrent Resolution' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :bill_type, 'hres' %><%= ' House Resolution' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :bill_type, 'sres' %><%= ' Senate Resolution' %>

  <%= f.label :bill_number, 'Bill number' %>
  <%= f.number_field :bill_number, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'form-control' %>

<% end %>
```

In my config/routes.rb file, I have the following line:

```
get '/bills/viewer', to: 'bills#show'
```

The idea is that I want the form to transfer the submitted information to the "show" action in my bills_controller.rb file, which I give below...

```
def show
  @bill = Bill.where("congress = ? AND bill_type = ? AND bill_number = ?", bill_params[:congress], bill_params[:bill_type], bill_params[:bill_number]).take
  if @bill.nil?
    create
  end
  @bill_xml = RestClient.get(bill_params[:bill_link])
  render :xml => @bill_xml
  puts "Called to show!"
```

...and then for the user to be redirected to corresponding show.html.erb file, which I give below...

```
<% provide(:title, "#{ @bill[:congress] } #{ @bill[:bill_type].upcase } #{ @bill[:bill_number] } | ") %>
<h1><%= "#{ @bill[:congress] } #{ @bill[:bill_type].upcase } #{ @bill[:bill_number] }" %></h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= puts @bill_xml %>
    <%= render @bill_xml %>
  </div>
</div>

<% puts "RENDERED..." %>
```

The two "puts" lines are in there for my own debugging purpose. The one in the show method behaves as expected, and my console displays "Called to show!". The other puts line, "RENDERED..." is not displayed. Moreover, the process completes to 200 OK.

I include my console's output upon clicking "Submit" below...

```
Started GET "/bills/viewer?utf8=%E2%9C%93&congress=112&bill_type=hr&bill_number=1027&commit=Submit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-05 15:05:51 -0700
Processing by BillsController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "congress"=>"112", "bill_type"=>"hr", "bill_number"=>"1027", "commit"=>"Submit"}
Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :commit
Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :commit
Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :commit
  Bill Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "bills".* FROM "bills" WHERE (congress = '112' AND bill_type = 'hr' AND bill_number = '1027') LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :commit
Called to show!
Completed 200 OK in 2980ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

But if the form were to be redirecting to show.html.erb the console output ought to return 3XX, no?

My (evidently wrong) understanding is that when I call the show action in my bills_controller, the website should automatically redirect to the views/bills/show.html.erb page. Why is this not the case, and how can I idiomatically correctly edit my code so that the desired redirect occurs?

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from Rails Guides:

"By default form_with submits forms using Ajax thereby skipping full page redirects. To make this guide easier to get into we've disabled that with local: true for now."

Answer (score 7):

The error was resolved by setting local: true within the form_with tag. Nevertheless, I am unclear as to why

Comment: From API Dock: (https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_with) By default form_with attaches the data-remote attribute submitting the form via an XMLHTTPRequest in the background if an Unobtrusive JavaScript driver, like rails-ujs, is used. Disable remote submits with local: true.